# Calcular días y meses restantes para el siguiente aniversario

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando contar cuántos días y meses faltan para el siguiente cumpleaños dada la fecha de nacimiento calculándola con la fecha actual, pero no logro obtener los días correctamente, únicamente los meses y creo que lo hago demasiado 'largo'.

> ¿Cómo puedo obtener los días restantes al aniversario dada la fecha?

**Código**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS naixement;
DELIMITER // 
CREATE FUNCTION naixement(par_data DATE) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(25)
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_messos INT DEFAULT FLOOR((1200 + DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m%d') - DATE_FORMAT(par_data,'%m%d'))/100);
    DECLARE var_dies INT DEFAULT FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, par_data, NOW()) % 30.4375);
    RETURN CONCAT(var_messos,' mesos i ',var_dies,' dies');
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

***Resolución***

```
DECLARE var_mesos INT DEFAULT ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,  DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'/',MONTH(par_data),'/',DAY(par_data))), 
                                                            DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'/',MONTH(NOW()),'/',DAY(par_data)))));

DECLARE var_dies INT DEFAULT ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'/',MONTH(par_data),'/',DAY(par_data))), 
                                                        DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'/',MONTH(par_data),'/',DAY(NOW())))));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En MySQL puedes usar la [función `DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

De la documentación (traducción libre del inglés...):

> `DATEDIFF()` devuelve `expr1 − expr2` expresado como un valor en días. `expr1` y `expr2` son expresiones de tipo ***date*** o
>   ***date-and-time***. Solo la parte ***date*** es usada en el cálculo.

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-11-30 23:59:59','2010-12-31');
        -> -31
```